# Show the sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_{n}>0 ,(n=1,2,\cdots)$ and   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{_{n}}}{a_{_{n+1}}+a_{_{n+2}}}=0.$$Show the sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is unbounded.

The following is my thoughts.But I am not sure my answer is right,I need someone to check it.Even though it's correct, this answer is complicated and cumbersome.Do you have some concise ways by **using reduction to absurdity**?

---

Suppose the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is bounded,then exists $M(>0)$ such that $0<a_{n}\leq M,(n=1,2,\cdots).$

***(1).*** 
$$0<\frac{a_{n}}{2M}\leq\frac{a_{_{n}}}{a_{_{n+1}}+a_{_{n+2}}},(n=1,2,\cdots)\Rightarrow\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=0 $$

***(2).*** 
$$\frac{a_{n}+a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}=A(n)+B(n),A(n)=\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}, B(n)=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}(B(n)\in (0,1],n=1,2,\cdots)\Rightarrow$$ $$0\leq\varlimsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+2}+a_{n+3}}=\varlimsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}\cdot \frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}{a_{n+2}+a_{n+3}}\leq\varlimsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}} \cdot\varlimsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n}+a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}=0\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+2}+a_{n+3}}=0$$

***(3).*** Futher,we have  $\forall p\in\mathbb{N},$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{_{n}}}{a_{_{n+p}}+a_{_{n+p+1}}}=0$$

***(4).***
 From ***(3)***,Let $$p_{1}=1, \exists N_{1}\in\mathbb {N},\text{such that}\frac{a_{_{n}}}{a_{_{n+1}}+a_{_{n+2}}}<\frac{1}{2}\text{ whenever} \quad n>N_{1};$$
$$p_{2}=2, \exists N_{2}\in\mathbb {N}(N_{2}>N_{1}),\text{such that}\frac{a_{_{n}}}{a_{_{n+2}}+a_{_{n+3}}}<\frac{1}{2}\text{ whenever} \quad n>N_{2};$$ $$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$$$$p_{k}=k, \exists N_{k}\in\mathbb {N}(N_{k}>N_{k-1}>\cdots>N_{1}),\text{such that}\frac{a_{_{n}}}{a_{_{n+k}}+a_{_{n+k+1}}}<\frac{1}{2}\text{ whenever} \quad n>N_{k};$$$$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$$
***(5).*** From ***(4)***,there must exists an index $k_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n_{0}>N_{k_{0}}$ such that $a_{n_{0}}>a_{n_{0}+k_{0}}$ and $a_{n_{0}}>a_{n_{0}+k_{0}+1}.$ In fact, If for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and every $n>N_{k},$ we have either $a_{n}\leq a_{n+k}$ or $a_{n}\leq a_{n+k+1},$ then for every $n>N_{k},a_{n}=0$.This is contradicting  $a_{n}>0 (n=1,2,\cdots)!$

***(6).*** From ***(5),***
$$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{a_{n_{0}}}{a_{n_{0}+k_{0}}+a_{n_{0}+k_{0}+1}}<\frac{1}{2}.
\quad \text{It's impossible!}$$

---

From above all,we can say the sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is unbounded.

Comment: The (5) is wrong."there must exists an index $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n_0>N_{k_0}$ such that $a_{n_0}>a_{n_0}+k_0$ and $a_{n_0}>a_{n_0}+k_0+1$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the limit hypothesis, for $n$ large enough,
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1} + a_{n+2}} < \frac{1}{4}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, either $a_{n+1} > 2 a_n$ or $a_{n+2} > 2 a_n$.  Using that, we can find a subsequence $a_{i_0}, a_{i_1}, \ldots$ such that $a_{i_n} \ge 2^n a_{i_0}$ (by choosing $i_{n+1}$ to be either $i_n + 1$ or $i_n + 2$).  That easily implies that the subsequence is unbounded, and therefore the original sequence is also unbounded.

Comment: Your answer is nice but common , I got this from my teaching assistant before.I am sorry I have forgotten to say I only need the proof by contradiction.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is bounded, that is to say,
there exists $M>0$ such that $$0<a_{n}\leq M,\ \ n=1,2,\cdots.$$
So
$$0<\frac{a_{n}}{2M}\leq\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0.$$
By
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0,$$
we know: for $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N>0$, when $n>N$,
$$a_n<\epsilon, \qquad \color{red}{\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}<\epsilon}.$$
So for any $k\geq1$,
\begin{align*}
a_{_{N+1}}
&\color{red}{<}(a_{_{N+2}}+a_{_{N+3}})\epsilon\\
&\color{red}{<}(a_{_{N+3}}+2a_{_{N+4}}+a_{_{N+5}})\epsilon^2\\
&\color{red}{<}(a_{_{N+4}}+3a_{_{N+5}}+3a_{_{N+6}}+a_{_{N+7}})\epsilon^3\\
&\color{red}{<}\cdots\\
&\color{red}{<}M\epsilon^k\left(1+\binom{k}{1}+\binom{k}{2}+\cdots+\binom{k}{k}\right)\\
&=M(2\epsilon)^k,
\end{align*}
Take $\epsilon=1/4$, then, for any $k\geq1$, we konw
$$0<a_{_{N+1}}<\frac{M}{2^k},$$
let $k\to\infty,$ we get $a_{_{N+1}}=0$, which is in contradiction with $a_{_{N+1}}>0$.